# Condition for checking NOT <null> value for NSString in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, if-statement

**Code:**

```
NSString *tempPhone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [personDict objectForKey:kPhoneKey]];
NSLog(@"NSString *tempPhone = %@",tempPhone);
```

**Output:**

```
NSString *tempPhone = <null>
```

Now I want to add if condition, for **not null**; I tried followings:

```
if (tempEmail != NULL)
if (tempPhone != Nil)
if (tempPhone != nil)
if (![tempPhone compare:@"<null>"])
if (tempPhone != (NSString*)[NSNull null])
```

I also Checked [this Post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839355/checking-a-null-value-in-objective-c-that-has-been-returned-from-a-json-string)

None of them is working for me. Where I am going wrong??

Comment: Did you implement `if([tempPhone length]==0)` condition? I think that would help you.

Comment: means you are getting length of string with null value?

Comment: Yes, It's "6". I think it's a string Containing "<null>"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following code

```
id phoneNo = [personDict objectForKey:kPhoneKey];

if( phoneNo && ![phoneNo isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] )
{
    NSString *tempPhone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [personDict objectForKey:kPhoneKey]];
    NSLog(@"NSString *tempPhone = %@",tempPhone);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"NSString *tempPhone is null");
}
```

Comment: Checking for NSNull class is a waste of runtime resources since in documentation it is specifically state that NSNull is a singleton. It is better to do [[NSNull null] isEquals:phoneNo] or just phoneNo == [NSNull null]. Both does pointer checking while the former give clarity.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/

Answer (score 1):

I think your `personDict` does not have an object for the key `kPhoneKey`, so it is returning `nil`.  When you format `nil` using `%@`, you get the string "`(null)`".

```
id object = [personDict objectForKey:kPhoneKey];
if (object) {
    NSString *tempPhone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object];
    NSLog(@"NSString *tempPhone = %@",tempPhone);
} else {
    // object is nil
}
```

Comment: The object wasn't nil; it was a string actually, with value "<null>". Thanks for your time rob.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (tempPhone != nil || [tempPhone isEqualToString:@"(null)"])
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's like this :

```
if (![tempPhone isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && tempPhone != nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

if ([str_name isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])

works for me...

Answer (score 0):

I Checked the webResponse (JSON, in my case).
It was returning me the string with value:

```
<null>
```

So, The following condition worked for me:

```
if (![tempPhone isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
```

Thanks for all your time. Thanks.

Comment: Normally it's not a string. It's a NSNull object.

Comment: And you check it like this : [tempPhone isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]

Answer (score 0):

Because `compare` method returns type `NSComparisonResult` which is defined as

```
enum _NSComparisonResult {NSOrderedAscending = -1, NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedDescending};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```

If the string is the same, it will return `NSOrderedSame` which have a `NSInteger` value of `0`.

Thus, the following line actually means...

```
if (![tempPhone compare:@"<null>"]) // `tempPhone` is equals to `@"<null>"`
```

or in a more understandable explanation, if `tempPhone` value is equal to `@"<null>"`.

You should write it as

```
if ([tempPhone compare:@"<null>"] != NSOrderedSame)
```

or

```
if (![tempPhone isEqualString:@"<null>"])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the string is having a null value. Example  in NSLog.. Implement this way..

```
  if ([StringName isKindOfClass:[NSNULL Class]]) {

   }
   else {

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First we need to check string length.**

if (tempPhone.length == 0)
  `

{

//Your String is having empty value (E.x, (null))

}

else

{

// You having some values in this string

}`