# How do I test for null in NSDictionary from SBJSON?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I've got an API returning a JSON encoded string of data that returns a real number or "null" as a value. As long as the JSON contains a numeric or string value, everything works as expected. If the key:value pair value is null, the code below crashes.

*How do I properly test NSDictionary objectForKey when it's getting a NULL from SBJSON?*

When the API returns a **null for filetype**, the code below crashes at the if() line.

My Objective-C code attempts to test for expected values:

```
if (1 == [[task valueForKey:@"filetype"] integerValue]) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

The API JSON output:

```
{"tclid":"3","filename":null,"filetype":null}
```

The NSLog() output of the NSDictionary is:

```
task {
    filename = "<null>";
    filetype = "<null>";
    tclid = 3;
}
```

Comment: Probable dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839355/checking-a-null-value-in-objective-c-that-has-been-returned-from-a-json-string/4839441#4839441 (though I answered it, so…I gave Josh +1, too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When transferring data from JSON to a Cocoa collection, the [`NSNull`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class is used to represent "no value", since Cocoa collections can't have empty slots. `<null>` is how `NSNull` prints itself.

To test for this, you can use `someObject == [NSNull null]`. It's a singleton -- there's only one instance of `NSNull` per process -- so pointer comparison works, although you may prefer to follow the usual Cocoa comparison convention and use `[someObject isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]`.

You're getting the crash because you're sending `integerValue` to that `NSNull` object. `NSNull` doesn't respond to `integerValue` and raises an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should first test if there is a value is null, if it is null performing the intValue method may crash your application.
Doing this should do.

```
if ([[task valueForKey:@"filetype"] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber Class]] && 1 == [[task valueForKey:@"filetype"] integerValue]) {
    // do something
} else {
     // do something else
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This will still crash because the object is not `nil`, it's the `NSNull` singleton. The first part of the expression will be true, and then you will send `intValue` to `[NSNull null]`, which doesn't respond to `intValue`. If the object _was_ `nil` (which isn't possible if it's in a collection), sending `intValue` would _not_ crash.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tried it really, I updated the answer to correct it. That should do.

Comment: That won't crash, but there's still no need to do the first test -- if it's not true (there is no value for that key in the dictionary) then neither will the second be (`[nil isKindOfClass:]` will return 0 like any message to `nil`).

Comment: Since the expression evaluates from left to right, [nil isKindOfClass:] will never happen since the first expression will be false.

Comment: Right, but there's no reason to do the first because the second will _never_ be true if the first is false. You can just use the second and have the same truth value.