# How to display string value in label when the value is null and some number

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uilabel

I have **JSON** object like this.

```
     {
        "id": "1",
        "subTotal": "20000.00",
        "total": "124565.00",
        "timeOfTrans": "3555525",
        "status": "1",
        "name": "gjgjgf",
        "email": "a@a.com",
        "level": "gjfgj",
        "teamId": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "subTotal": null,
        "total": null,
        "timeOfTrans": null,
        "status": null,
        "name": "Rajendra",
        "email": "b@b.com",
        "level": "gfjgfjg",
        "teamId": "1"
    }
```

I want to display **JSON** string "total" in label. When "total" is null i want to display '0' when "total" is some number i want to display that number in same label.

Here i`m trying this code

```
totalLbl=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
id total = [currentEmplyCellDit objectForKey:@"total"];
if ([total isKindOfClass:(id)[NSNull null]])
{
    //Your value of total is NULL
    totalLbl.text = @"0";
}
//Show the Value.
totalLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",total];
```

this code displaying correctly but i shows null in label when "total" is null.

I want to display 0 when "total" is NULL

How to Solve this...
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make condition to check null in your string and then replace this with whatever you want.

```
id yourValue=[youJSONDict objectForKey:@"total"];;
if ([yourValue isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    yourLabel.text=@"0";
}
else{
    yourLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourValue];
}
```

Comment: i`m display label in table view.

Comment: It display <null> when "total" value is NULL. I want to display 0 when "total" value NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 if([dictionary valueForKey:@"total"] != nil) {
      // The key existed..
 }
 else {
       // No joy...
 }
```

And remember this thing 
:

```
   objectForKey will return nil if a key doesn't exist


  Symbol    Value            Meaning
  =======   =============   =========================================
   NULL     (void *)0       literal null value for C pointers
   nil      (id)0           literal null value for Objective-C objects
   Nil      (Class)0        literal null value for Objective-C classes
  NSNull    [NSNull null]   singleton object used to represent null
```

and see my answer [Checking a null value from Json response in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668263/checking-a-null-value-from-json-response-in-objective-c/16668483#16668483)

Answer (score 1):

Just call one of these function using the dictionary or array whatever you are receiving from the JSON. These functions will remove all NULL values from your response.

You have to write both functions they are calling each other recursively.

Call like these...

```
        NSMutableDictionary * ResponseDict =(NSMutableDictionary *)[responseString JSONValue];
        ResponseDict = [self removeNullFromDictionary:ResponseDict];
        NSLog(@"ResponseDict = %@",ResponseDict);
```

This is the function for Dictionary.

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)removeNullFromDictionary : (NSMutableDictionary *)dict
{

    for (NSString * key in [dict allKeys])
    {
        if ([[dict objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            [dict setValue:@"" forKey:key];
        }
        else if ([[dict objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]||[[dict objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            [dict setObject:[self removeNullFromDictionary:[dict objectForKey:key]] forKey:key];
        }
        else if ([[dict objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]||[[dict objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            [dict setObject:[self removeNullFromArray:[dict objectForKey:key]] forKey:key];
        }

    }

    return dict;
}
```

This is the function for array

```
-(NSMutableArray *)removeNullFromArray : (NSMutableArray *)arr
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt<[arr count]; cnt++)
    {
        if ([[arr objectAtIndex:cnt] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:cnt withObject:@""];
        }
        else if ([[arr objectAtIndex:cnt] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]||[[arr objectAtIndex:cnt] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:cnt withObject:[self removeNullFromDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)[arr objectAtIndex:cnt]]];
        }
        else if ([[arr objectAtIndex:cnt] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]||[[arr objectAtIndex:cnt] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:cnt withObject:[self removeNullFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)[arr objectAtIndex:cnt]]];
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

This will definitely help you. Must try.....

Answer (score 0):

```
if([currentEmplyCellDit objectForKey:@"total"] == [NSNull null]) 
{
  yourLbl.text=@"0";
}
else
{
  yourLbl.text = [currentEmplyCellDit objectForKey:@"total"]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be good if you would edit your answer and add some explanation why this code answers the question. Just pasting a block of code is not that helpful.